# ModelItem and ModelTreeManager not found.System.Activities.Presentation is missing .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I need to use ModelItem and ModelTreeManager, but visual studio did not find reference to using System.Activities.Presentation.Model in .net core 3.1

.net core 3.1 CoreWf provides the classes in the System.Activity(.Net Framework 4.x) namespace but not System.Activity.Presentation so ModelItem and ModelTreeManager are not accessible.

I´m triying to migrate a class from.net framework to dot net core 3.1

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Activities.Presentation;
    using CoreWf;

    namespace Utils.Converters
    { 
            public class ClassTest
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                object convertedValue = null;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    ModelItem argumentModelItem = value as ModelItem;
                    if (argumentModelItem != null &&
                        argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"] != null &&
                        argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"].Value != null)
                    {
                        convertedValue = argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"].Value;
                    }
                }
                return convertedValue;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                Argument target = null;
                ArgumentDirection direction = ArgumentDirection.In;
                string directionString = parameter?.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directionString))
                {
                    direction = (ArgumentDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(ArgumentDirection), directionString);
                }

                ActivityWithResult expression = value as ActivityWithResult;
                ModelItem valueExpressionModelItem = value as ModelItem;
                if (valueExpressionModelItem != null && typeof(ActivityWithResult).IsAssignableFrom(valueExpressionModelItem.ItemType))
                {
                    expression = (ActivityWithResult)valueExpressionModelItem.GetCurrentValue();
                }

                if (expression != null)
                {
                    Type argumentType;
                    argumentType = direction == ArgumentDirection.In ? expression.ResultType : expression.ResultType.IsGenericType ? expression.ResultType.GetGenericArguments()[0] : expression.ResultType;
                    try
                    {
                        target = Argument.Create(argumentType, direction);
                        target.Expression = expression;
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine(err.ToString());
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                var mtm = new ModelTreeManager(valueExpressionModelItem.GetEditingContext());
                return mtm.CreateModelItem(null, target);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @PopeDev, please post your code into the question and do not link to an image, this will help us figure out what is going on and what specific things you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Slipoch thaks for feedback

Comment: no worries @PopeDev, good work on the edit. :)
I haven't used these classes so I do not know the answer, but there may be something in the TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @orosandrei for explain to me.The actual situation is that CoreWF helps with the runtime + etw. Presentation / rehosted designer are not available unfortunately.. for this I have to stay with .net framework 4x

[Explain with detail in this link](https://andreioros.com/blog/windows-workflow-foundation-net-core/)